# Golang map containing both string and integer

Tags: json, go, types, marshalling

I am trying to create a JSON string from a map using JSON.Marshal() in golang. However, the int values are being displayed as strings surrounded by double quotes.

My code is outputting:

```
{ "age":
    {
        "$gt":"22",
        "$lt":"20"
    },
  "location":
    {
        "$eq":"london"
    },
  "name":{
        "$eq":"fred"
    }
}
```

instead of

```
{ "age":
    {
        "$gt":22,
        "$lt":20
    },
  "location":
    {
        "$eq":"london"
    },
  "name":{
        "$eq":"fred"
    }
}
```

I am using:

```
var output_map = map[string]map[string]string{}

//Populate map here

output_json, err := json.Marshal(output_map)

if err!= nil {
    fmt.Println("Error encoding JSON")
}

fmt.Println(output_json)
```

My understanding is that JSON.Marshal() will print the integers correctly if they are supplied but my map won't contain integers. I could change my map to map[string]map[string]int{} but then it wouldn't contain the string values for 'name' and 'location'.

The ultimate problem is that I need the map to contain both int and string values. Some sort of map[string]map[string]{}.

How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Harry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you cannot describe your data with a properly typed struct then consider using a map with values of type `interface{}` (essentially any type):

```
output_map := map[string]map[string]interface{}{}
```

For example:

```
output_map := map[string]map[string]interface{}{
  "age": {
    "$gt": 18,
  },
  "location": {
    "eq": "London",
  },
}
bytes, err := json.MarshalIndent(&output_map, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
// {
//   "age": {
//     "$gt": 18
//   },
//   "location": {
//     "eq": "London"
//   }
// }
```

Of course, using the `interface{}` type is not a best-practice; however, it's sometimes the only way to accomplish certain things.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

We can declare variable for mix mapping with integer,string as below.

```
var variable_name = map[string]interface{}{}
```

e.g.

```
var variable_name = map[string]interface{}{
        "name": c.String("name"),
        "age":  c.Int("age"),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with maerics,

`map[string]interface{}` would be the way to go, if you have to avoid structs.

From your content I assume, that you are dealing with mongodb-queries.
So maybe the following code helps.

If you are going to query mongodb from go I would recommend the mgo-driver **mgo.v2**.
It implements a custom type **bson.M** which is the same as mentioned above, but works also for querying the db.

Beside this, it makes the code more readable.

**Sample:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {

    bsonMap := bson.M{
        "age": bson.M{
            "$gt": 22,
            "$lt": 20,
        },
        "location": bson.M{"$eq": "london",},
        "name":     bson.M{"$eq": "fred"},
    }

    bytes, err := json.Marshal(bsonMap)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}
```

Comment: Thanks nulldog. Yes, I am using mongodb queries. I wasn't aware of this import but it looks very useful

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected: `map[string]map[string]string{}` contains only string values, so `json.Marshal(interface{})` return `json string` with marshaled `string` values.

I think you should use `struct` instead of `map`. Just create a struct, something like this:

```
type Age struct {
    Gt  int `json:"gt"`
    Lt  int `json:"lt"`
}

type Person struct {
    Age         Age     `json:"age"`
    Location    string  `json:"location"`
    Name        string  `json:"name"`
}
```

And just marshal it with standart `json.Marshal(interface{})` method.
(in this code `json` tags isn't required, but you can use it if you want to change names of fields in serialized json string)

I create `test.go` file with following code in `main()`:

```
person := Person{
    Age{
        22,
        20,
    },
    "London",
    "Fred",
}

serialized, e := json.Marshal(person)
if e != nil {
    fmt.Println(e)
    return
}

fmt.Println(string(serialized))
```

and it returns this:

```
{
    "age":
    {
        "gt":22,
        "lt":20
    },
    "location":"London",
    "name":"Fred"
}
```

**P.S.** I can't recommend you to use `map[string]map[string]interface{}` because in this case you need to have custom `Unmarshaller` (to fill up your `map` back). With structs you can unmarshal it by this way:

```
deserialized := Person{}
e = json.Unmarshal(serialized, &deserialized)
if e != nil {
    fmt.Println("can't deserialize:", e)
    return
}
```